# MIPS Attempt to execute non instruction when using branch

Tags: mips32, spim

Could anyone please help me to figure out what causes my program to show Attempt to execute non instruction at 0x00400140, when I uncomment the beqz line. If I keep it commented my program runs just fine, but just as I uncomment it it shows the error at random times (i.e. sometimes after 5 seconds, sometimes after 10 seconds, etc). (The program is basically a timer and I am using beqz to only print once each second)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

main:

```
addi $t0, $zero, 60             # stores 60 in $t0
div $s0, $t0                    # divides total time by 60

mflo $s1                    # stores minutes in $s1
mfhi $s2                    # stores seconds in $s2

#beqz $s4, skip
#nop

move $s3, $ra                   # stores $ra in $s3 

move $a0, $s1                   # stores minute value in $a0
jal printToAscii                # calls function to print minute

la $a0, colon                   # loads colon address in $a0
jal printColon                  # calls function to print colon

move $a0, $s2                   # stores second value in $a0
jal printToAscii                # calls function to print second

jal EraseLine

move $ra, $s3                   # restores $ra
addi $s4, $zero, 0
```

skip:

```
j main
nop
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, my exception handler kept skipping the line so the j main line got skipped.